# Host CRM Dynamics in iframe contained within a custom website, with custom website acting as parent

Tags: dynamics-crm, twilio-flex

Is it possible today to use an iframe to host Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Specifically, I would like to have a custom application (acting as PARENT most web application) which has an iframe displaying Microsoft Dynamics CRM (say, default home page of CRM). The custom application would have a collapsable/expandable area which would consume about 50-70% of the web application user interface. This collapsable expandable area would simply be an iframe with Microsoft Dynamics CRM taking up about 50-70% of the user interface real estate.

I need the iframe URL to be any URL I would normally browse to on the Dynamics CRM such that I can do just about anything I would normally do with the CRM in a browser tab as I can in the iframe.

For reference:
Parent Application = Twilio Flex 'Agent Desktop'

Is this possible? Thank you advance.

Comment: may be I understood it as naive, but can you not pass url of dynamics as source to your iframe and then it will work just like normal website just under your Iframe?

Comment: @AnkUser, no I can’t pass the url of dynamics and have it work. It appears there is some errors that lead me to believe there are restrictions Microsoft has placed for hosting dynamics within iframe. I need someone who is knowledgeable of this use case, that is, hosting dynamics within iframe